# Javascript not loading in Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I have a single page application.With header, footer and content sections. 
Header and footer part will be loaded one time. For consecutive navigation the content page will be loaded (its simple MVC plugin). The content page has Jave scripts it needed.

My issues is when I load the content page for the first time the java script is loading. And if I navigate to some other page and revisit to the page the Java script will not be called again.

For example say I have content page PageA and it has java script reference for Myscript.js.I have simple alert in Myscript.js. When I load PageA for first time I'm getting alert. But if I navigate to PageB and come to PageA I'm not getting the alert.

Comment: What do you mean by come to PageA again ? are you redirecting the user to that page or just closing a frame (which can be PageB) inside it ?..

Comment: It means loading PageA.cshtml navigating to PageB.cshtml and coming back to  PageA.cshtml

Comment: You need to clear out which solution you've used for changing these pages one after each other. "navigating to", "coming back!", "going there", these phrases can be implemented in so many different ways.